# Why is my .Net app only using single NUMA node?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, numa

I have a server with 2 NUMA node with 16 CPUs each. I can see all the 32 CPUs in task manager, first 16 (NUMA node 1) in the first 2 rows and the next 16 (NUMA node 2) in the last 2 rows.

In my app I am starting 64 threads, using `Thread.Start()`. When I run the app, it's CPU intensive, only the first 16 CPUs are busy, the other 16 CPUs are idle.

Why? I am using `Interlocked.Increment()` a lot. Could this be a reason?
Is there a way I can start threads on a specific NUMA node?

Answer (score 10):

In addition to `gcserver` we should enable [`GCCpuGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925566%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Thread_UseAllCpuGroups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj665638%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so the config should be more like:

```
<configuration
   <runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
      <GCCpuGroup  enabled="true"/>
      <Thread_UseAllCpuGroups  enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

`GcCpuGroup` enables Garbage Collection for multiple CPU groups and `Thread_UseAllCpuGroups` enables manage thread distribution across all CPU groups for the runtime.

Answer (score 4):

First thing to check would be indeed the `app.config` making sure the necessary options are set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="true" />
        <Thread_UseAllCpuGroups enabled="true" />
        <GCCpuGroup enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
    <startup> 
        <!-- 4.5 and later should work, use the one targeted -->
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>       
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

If `app.config`-Wizadry isn't helping, is likely that your machine uses multiple kernel groups (Kgroups) when it shouldn't. You can then check your BIOS for `NUMA Group Size Optimization` if you have Gen9 HP. If it is in `Clustered` mode, the current CLR (2017, .net 4.6.2) only utilizes the first one. If you have no more than 64 cores in that machine, you should be able select the `Flat` layout which puts all cores in the same group. If you cannot find it, [you may need a BIOS Update](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=5379860&docId=emr_na-c04650594&docLocale=en_US).

For lot more details see [Unable to use more than one processor group for my threads in a C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28098082/303290) here on StackOverflow. It even comes with its own [diagnostics tool](https://github.com/EricOuellet2/SharpTestProcessorThreading).

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the garbage collector to the server version?

In app.config, try:

```
<configuration
   <runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Because of the way the heaps are allocated the server GC makes a massive difference when churning a lot of objects/data on a lot of threads in a machine with many cores.

Comment: This setting does not change the behavior.