# only half of logical cores run on windows server 2012

Tags: environment-variables, multicore, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

i'm using windows server 2012 on a machine with 2 processors-12 cores each, total of 24 cores.
when i look in the task manager i see 24 cores.
also when i run the command 
`cpu get numberofcores,numberoflogicalprocessors /format:list`
on the WMIC i get:

> NumberOfCores=12
>   NumberOfLogicalProcessors=12
>
> NumberOfCores=12 
>   NumberOfLogicalProcessors=12

however, in the environment variables i get:
`NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` = 12
and when i run in the CMD: 
`echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` i get 12 also..

which means i get to use only half of the available processors.

ideas how to solve it?

Comment: are you running 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I'm running a 64-bit machine

Comment: ok. hmmm one think i can think of is maybe it is only listing the number of cores on one cpu and not both, since they each have 12 and you are getting 12.

Comment: that might be the issue..  but how can i solve it? when i try to read the number of processors via java Runtime i get the wrong number..  i read somewhere that on win server 2008 there was an issue with AMD64 architecture (same architecture that my machine uses) that was solves by a hotfix - yet i couldn't find any reference to it on windows 2012

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly the same problem till now, but when I changed BIOS parameter  "Node Interleaving" from Disabled to Enabled - WOW! 7z/winrar now see all and USE all cores (logical processors) and ENV variable "number of processors" is 24 now!
But it is work-around.
Other way - if you use HP DL3*0 G9 platform - there is another solution - you must change setting: "NUMA Group Size Optimization" from [Clustered - default] to [Flat]. I've got this solution from another [thread at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098082/unable-to-use-more-than-one-processor-group-for-my-threads-in-a-c-sharp-app). That's helped me too and I think it right solution.

Comment: wow, that was long ago...  i solved it back then by writing a dll file that checks the number of logical cores, and importing it using JNI