# Run batch file on specific processor

Tags: batch-file

I have a server with dual processors, that is multiple cores per processor and two physical Xenon processors.

Each process will only run on one processor, which is fine. If you start a multi-threaded app it can only use the maximum amount of cores on one physical processor, not both (Windows 10 limitation?). I would like to start two instances of the same program so that I can use all cores on both the processors.

How do I start a process from a batch file so that it runs on a specified processor group? I.e. Cores 0-16 of processor 1, or Cores 0-16 of processor 2?

I've tried:

```
start /affinity FF file.exe
```

But that only runs it on cores from one particular processor. I believe I need to set the processor group but how do I do that using the 'start' command?

I can see you can use hexadecimal masks for the affinity with 'start' but that only seems to work on the cores of the first processor, I can't seem to access the cores of the second processor.

Since there is much confusion over my question, please see below. It's from task manager when you try and set an affinity, notice how I have multiple processor groups? That's what I am trying to configure using the 'start' command. '/affinity' only uses cores from group 0.

[image: Multiple processor groups]

Comment: MSDOS is not a multi-tasking OS. Did you consider switching to Linux ?

Comment: You should not care on which CPUs the stuff is running, that is the business of the OS and can change very often. But search "CPU affinity"

Comment: @GerhardBarnard sorry, thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: OK, another go - your "Processor group" combo-box perhaps indicates that you have NUMA nodes. [This question talks about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28098082/1270789), so you might be able to say `start /node 1` to use the second CPU. Furthermore, I would guess you can combine `/node` and `/affinity` to run on selected cores in each physical CPU.

Comment: @KenY-N thanks that worked. node 1 accesses the second processor. Write it up in a quick answer and I'll up vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your "Processor group" combo, it appears that you have the system set to present [NUMA nodes](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.resourcemanagement.doc_41/using_numa_systems_with_esx_esxi/c_what_is_numa.html) with each physical CPU being assigned to a single node. [This question talks about how to check the config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28098082/1270789), so assuming that that is how you are set up, the command line flag `/node <NUMA index>` would allow you to select which node, so we get:

```
start /node 1 file.exe
```

This should start the application on the second NUMA node. Note that you might be able to combine this with the `/affinity` flag, so to run on just two cores of the first node, the following might work:

```
start /node 0 /affinity 3 file.exe
```