# Is PLINQ limited to one NUMA Node? Or: Am I affected by HP Gen9 c04650594?

Tags: .net, multiprocessing, plinq, numa

I recently noticed that LINQ's `AsParallel` only utilizes half the cores on one of our soon to be production systems. So I wrote a tiny benchmark in LINQPad:

```
// should terminate with an AggregatException containing t overflows
// where t is the number of threads used
Enumerable.Range(0,Int32.MaxValue).AsParallel().Select(i=>
    Enumerable.Range(0,i).Select(j=>(long)j).Sum()
    +Enumerable.Range(0,Int32.MaxValue-i).Select(k=>(long)k).Sum()
).Sum()
```

Running this piece of code on a 2 socket (16C/32T) system only shows 16 busy cores (and finishes with 16 overflows for that matter), which leads me to the initial Question: *Is PLINQ limited a one Socket/NUMA Node*? Or what is the limiting factor here?

**Update**

`Environment.ProcessorCount.Dump("detected processor count");` is 16 instead of 32 so that may be the cause for PLINQ using only 16 worker threads in the first place. But then again, when explicitly using `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(32)` also only 16 cores are used.

[It looks like we're also affected by the HP ProLiant Gen9 / Xeon E5 2600v3 Kgroup Clustred vs Flat configuration.](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=5379860&docId=emr_na-c04650594&docLocale=en_US). If you have 64 or less cores, use `flat` and you can utilize all cores again. However, if you have more cores you there seems to be no solution at the moment.

The question whether PLINQ is limited to a NUMA Node still remains. My guess is: It doesn't care about NUMA nodes and it only uses the first kernel group.

Comment: Wow - I searched some time and didn't find the [referenced duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26830237/303290). I won't delete this question though, b/c that question obviously needs better google ranking. Unfortunately it doesn't have a post that fully answers the question. At least [this config](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35981932/303290) is only somewhat helpful as you have more to google (it doesn't get me to use all cores!) - @user3473830 you seem to know your stuff, why not improve your question so datadev can make it the accepted answer?

Comment: Related but different question: [c# Environment.ProcessorCount does not always return the full number of Logical Processor, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27965962/303290)

Comment: While not answering the initial question, [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098082/unable-to-use-more-than-one-processor-group-for-my-threads-in-a-c-sharp-app) really helped understanding the underlying problem